# Inorder Traversal of QuadTree

Tags: c++, quadtree

So I am trying to do an inorder traversal of my quadtree, but I am not sure how to modify my code from a BST to a quadtree. Instead of printing left, root, right. I want to print NE, NW, root, SE, SW. Anyway this project is in c++ but java or anything else works too.

```
void printInOrder(BST node)
{
    if(node != nullptr)
    {
        printInOrder(node->left);
        cout << node->name << endl;
        printInOrder(node->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why tag java when this is strictly c++ syntax?

Comment: @MT756 well i may have written the code in c++ but someone could answer in java too, anything works bc they're similar enough.

Comment: What does `displayPreorder` do? Why are both in-order and pre-order functions being mixed?

Comment: That's not how tagging works. Only use applicable language tags--if it's anything goes, using a language-agnostic algorithm tag. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question).

Comment: @SacrificerXY ive corrected the mistake now my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you call`displayPreorder` inside `printInOrder`

But the concept to print a quad tree and a binary tree is the same

```
void printInOrder(Quadtree node)
{
    if(node != nullptr)
    {
        printInOrder(node->NE);
        printInOrder(node->NW);
        cout << node->name << endl;
        printInOrder(node->SE);
        printInOrder(node->SW);
    }
}
```